# The benefit of Eigendecomposition of DCT and DST

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, cosine, eigendecomposition

I am Ph.D in pure mathematics and interested in signal processing.

Theoretically, any illustration of the eigendecomposition of the discrete trigonometric transforms (DTTs) is worthwhile.

Q. What real applications can be followed by having  the eigendecomposition of the discrete sine and cosine transforms? Any reference is appreciated.

Comment: You're putting the cart in front of the horse. "Theoretically, any illustration of {something} is worthwhile": Beg to differ, that's not the case! Same is true for the DFT: the EVD of the DFT is surprisingly complicated and has to the best of my knowledge no direct application in signal processing!

Comment: You can of course always *come up* with an application – but that would feel like a question too broad. Maybe it's more promising to take this from the other side. You're a pure mathematician, so DTTs are already plenty applied math for you; from which side did you come, and how did you end up caring about the DCT, DST, and their spectra?

Comment: Oh, **you haven't accepted an answer in more than 2 years**. Please fix that! Not accepting answers if you got one that answers your question is bad style and hurtful to the effects that drive this community. I won't consider writing an answer in this extreme case!

Comment: Many thanks for all your comments, however I could not find any proper clue in your statements.

Comment: I have a general question.  Are the eigenfuctions that are the result of the eigendecomposition, simply the cosines of the basis of the DCT and the sines that are the basis of the DST?

Comment: "the EVD of the DFT ... has ... no direct application in signal processing!"  Well, the fact that all the eigenvalues have magnitude 1 means that the DFT is about as well-conditioned numerically as you can possibly get.  This saves you a lot of time trying to find something _better_, or worrying about it in general.

Comment: @TimWescott yep, but that's not really an application, that's kind of a condition as to why it makes sense to have unitary transforms in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is a question:

We know that if we define the DFT as:

$$\begin{align}
 X[k] &= \mathcal{DFT} \Big\{ x[n] \Big\} \\
      &\triangleq \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] \, e^{-j2\pi nk/N}
\end{align} $$

and

$$ y[n] \triangleq X[n]  $$

(note the substitution of $n$ in for $k$.)  then

$$ Y[k] = \mathcal{DFT} \Big\{ y[n] \Big\} $$

then, if the DFT is defined as above:

$$ Y[n] = x[-n] $$

where periodicity is implied:  $x[n+N]=x[n]$ for all $n$.

Now, if we require even symmetry

$$x[n] = x[-n] \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

then the DFT, $X[k]$, will also have even symmetry and two repeated operations of the DFT will result in the original input.  So then define

$$ y[n] \triangleq x[n] + X[n] $$

And we will know that

$$\begin{align}
 Y[k] &= \mathcal{DFT} \Big\{ y[n] \Big\} \\
      &= y[k] \\
\end{align}$$

So, from that, all sorts of eigenfunctions can be defined.  Then we gotta make sure that they form a basis.  But it wouldn't have to be pure sinusoids.